# head js + jquery.validate.unobtrusive + custom validators

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using `head.js` (http://headjs.com) to do async loading of my javascripts.

I have problem with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and custom validators

All custom validations should be loaded after `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`, and I do it like following:

```
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Script("jquery")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Script("head.load")"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- entire markup -->
    <script>
    head.js("@Url.Script("jquery.validate")", function () {
            head.js("@Url.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive")", function () {
                    head.js("@Url.Script("custom-validations")");
                });                
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The problem is that `custom-validations` script should be loaded after `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` but before `document.onready` event, because `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` uses `document.onready` to do it's black magic. But, when I'm using `head.js` `document.onready` event fired before scripts starts to load, and my custom validation does not work.

Is there any common solutions/workarounds to solve this kind of problems with async script loading?

Another problem that my customer does not want to see `jquery.validate`/`jquery.validate.onubtrusive` in `<head>` tag.

---

`@Url.Script` - helper method for locating js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution by myself. Need to use [jQuery.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) to hold 'document.ready' while all scripts depend on jquery.validate.unobtrusive will not load.

```
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Script("jquery")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Script("head.load")"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- entire markup -->
    <script>
        head.js("@Url.Script("jquery.validate")", function () {
            $.holdReady(true); // set semaphore for dom ready. 
            head.js("@Url.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive")", function () {
                    head.js("@Url.Script("custom-validations")", function () { //fires when all provided scripts are loaded
                        $.holdReady(false); // release semaphore and fire event
                    });
            });                
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#the_form_in_question') after the load.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I need a generic solution and validation.unobtrusive just a good example for the problem

Comment: $().trigger("ready") perhaps... jQuery ought to fire .ready() requests as soon as they are added if document.onReady has already fired. Since they aren't firing, however, it could be that head.js is somehow interfering with that. Alternatively, be aware that unobtrusive will only validate the form once. You need to reset the validations and parse again after that point.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
head.ready("@Url.Script("jquery.validate")", function () {
    head.ready("@Url.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive")", function () {
        head.ready("@Url.Script("custom-validations")",function(){
            // your code here
        });
    });                
});
```

If you use jquery, you could add the scripts via `getScript` method which fires a callback when the script is loaded, so that can help :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("@Url.Script("jquery.validate")",function(){
          $.getScript("@Url.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive")",function(){
              $.getScript("@Url.Script("custom-validations")",function(){
                  // do your stuff here
              });
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: $.getScript loads scripts via xhr and does not allow to private-cache them.

Comment: Also you've not answered the question. The problem described in question still present in your example.